# Click the link, if we have only class name

Tags: python, selenium, getelementsbyclassname

How can I click the link:

```
<a class="single_like_button btn3-wrap" onclick="openFbLWin_189932();">
<span>&nbsp;</span><div class="btn3">Share</div>
</a>
```

This is my code in Python, but it doesn't work. I use Selenium

```py
......
elem = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("single_like_button btn3-wrap")[0].click(); 
......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[find_elements_by_class_name()](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_class_name) is apparently limited to a single class name.

You can use [find_element_by_css_selector()](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_css_selector) instead and write:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
    ".single_like_button.btn3-wrap").click();
```

Comment: Thank's its work !!!
Befor my post, i use 
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.single_like_button btn3-wrap").click()
but it not worked.
Thank You.

Comment: Of course it would be. Otherwise it should be called "find_elements_by_class_names", in which case, it ends up being practically identical to a CSS selector.